# Flask:Python - How to check IP address of the request

Tags: python, flask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get ip address of visitors using Python (specifically Flask micro-framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759981/get-ip-address-of-visitors-using-python-specifically-flask-micro-framework)

I'm creating REST api with flask. I want to allow requests only from one (or more later on) IP addresses. How do I check for IP address in my view?

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759981/get-ip-address-of-visitors-using-python-specifically-flask-micro-framework

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51928942/5588862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the headers from [Incoming Request Data](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data) and find the `REMOTE_ADDR`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using google app engine you would use self.request.remote_addr