# Why is remote_addr missing from the Flask documentation?

Tags: python, flask

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760309) answers how to find the IP of your visitors in Flask. The code works. However, `request.remote_addr` seems to be absent from the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#incoming-request-data). Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [`Request`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest) object comes from Werkzeug, where it *is* [documented](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.remote_addr).  Flask's docs just copy over some of the more commonly used information, but they do link directly to the Werkzeug docs too.