# Python, Flask client ip address

Tags: python, flask

I need to log the IP address of every user of my webapp, that I've created with Python and Flask.

I'm using

```
request.remote_addr
```

But that's return the IP address of the server the app is deployed to. Any fixes to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IP address of visitors using Python + Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759981/get-ip-address-of-visitors-using-python-flask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you deploy the flask application?

I guess you deploy your app via a reverse-proxy server like nginx, right?

If you did that then `request.remote_addr` is the address of your server because your server sent client's request to your application and sent the response to the client.

To fix this, see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups

Comment: I deploy the app with supervisor on AWS

Comment: Actually, I found out that this `request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', request.remote_addr)` works well for my needs

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to get the user's(also known as client) IP is to set this as a variable or use it directly.

`request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']`

To get your server's IP:

`request.remote_addr`

Comment: `request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']` and `request.remote_addr` are the same thing (and not solving the problem the OP asked about.)