# request.environ.get for getting visitors IP on reverse proxy.

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, pythonanywhere

I tried the solution here on [Python, Flask client ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376668/python-flask-client-ip-address). Everything works fine on the HTML side. But if I put this on python code (my app.py file) it shows different IPs.

**On my App.py**

`ip_add = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)` #shows ip on amazon. idk what I am doing wrong

**On my index.html**

`{{request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)}}` #this works fine

Im running it on pythonanywhere by the way. Thanks and good day!

Comment: are you running **App.py** on your local machine?

Comment: no sir. Its deployed now (Feb, 11, 2018) at http://skrmnghrd.pythonanywhere.com/ as you can see, it says welcome + your ip. but on the lower part (which is request.environ.get on python side) shows the ip of the amazon

Comment: What's the Amazon IP that it's showing?

Comment: 52.91.216.5. this is the amazon Ip that is showing. Im working on a javascript code in the meantime so I can make this functionality

Comment: Hmm.  That's the IP address of the proxy server that free PythonAnywhere accounts use to access the Internet.  Are you sure you're looking at the same requests in each of the two cases?

Comment: Another thing- did you reload your webapp after making those changes? In particular, your template file might be re-rendered on each request but the webapp code wouldn't automatically update and requires a reload on PythonAnywhere.