# Docker get user's real ip

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a Flask website running inside of a docker container. I would like to display the user's ip address to them, however it currently displays the IP address of the docker container, probably due to it being forwarded from docker. 
I retrieve the IP address using Flask's `requests` module.

It shouldn't make a difference, but I am using docker-compose.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

This is the code for the website using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis(host='redis', port=6379)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = redis.incr('hits')
    return 'Your IP is: {0}. I have been visited {1} times and \'foo\' is set to {2}.\n'.format(request.remote_addr,count, redis.get('foo').decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

I know that Nginx gives the request a header with the ip address before it was forwarded that you can use. Does Docker have anything similar that I can use or is there another approach. [Get IP address of visitors using Python + Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759981/get-ip-address-of-visitors-using-python-flask)

Example of current behavior: [image: example]

Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean their external IP? Like using [ipify](http://api.ipify.org)?

Comment: Yes, like using ipify, although I could use their API I'd still be interested in doing it myself.

Comment: I wanted to do it myself, to learn about docker

Comment: You need an external service to give you that information. There's no other way to determine it. So you can either make your own ipify-type service, or just use that one. It's impossible to observe from the inside what your IP is, there's always too many layers of NAT in the way.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: How is this deployed? You may be able to get the IP. How are you configuring NGINX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with the comments. Depending on how much of the deployment you are in control of this is doable. You should add something like the following to the NGINX config:

```
      location / {
          proxy_pass  http://web;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
```