# How to get Client/User IP Address visiting my webpage in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have been referring to lot of posts on Javascript alone cant get the Client IP.

True,but got some solution which helped me achieve my goal partially,as it works on Chrome but NOT on IE.

Also the ActiveX support cant be provided for IE and cant use Third party APIs.

Also the php support is not present on the hosted Server(not much changes can be done to server,but yes,i can do to my code).

Please suggest on how to proceed and how to get Client unique IP and not the server IP through IE.
The working code on Chrome is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || 
window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;  
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), 
noop = function(){}; 

pc.createDataChannel("");  
pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);   
pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){ 
if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;

var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4})
{7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];

alert(myIP)


pc.onicecandidate = noop;

}; 
});


</script>
</html>
```

Tried solutions:
[python flask hosted server doesnt return my client IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990258/python-flask-hosted-server-doesnt-return-my-client-ip)

Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? User count has to be done server side. or is your question how to get the data (evaluated by the server) of users who visited the page?

Comment: Hi,Either way is fine.Goal is to achieve the user IP address visiting my page.And like as mentioned in problem statement on the measures i have taken so far but failed to achieve on IE.Success on Chrome.

Comment: If i get the IP,i have my APIs to make out the count and process further.Now what i require to know the user IP everytime he visits the page.

Comment: Any input on the query??

Comment: Do you get any ip at all when you try the flask solution?

Comment: `Hi,Either way is fine` no - it is just impossible to track the users IP adresses on the client side. You need to do this on the server side

Comment: or maybe i still don't get your problem

Comment: Yes i do get server ip not the client/user ip when i use python flask api

Comment: How i came to know,as the ip for 2 different user was same when returned from flask