# Python3: Print request's IP from flask_restful's get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

Here is my get method of my `Resource` class:

```py
from flask_restful import Resource
import subprocess

CMD = ['some', 'cmd' ]

class MyResource(Resource):

    def get(self):

        try:
            completed_process = subprocess.run(CMD, check=True, 
                                               capture_output=True)
      ....
```

At which point in the above code can I retrieve (and print) the IP of the incoming `XGET` request?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759981/get-ip-address-of-visitors-using-flask-for-python) answer but it does not indicate how to go about it with `flask_restful` and the `Resource` class.

Comment: unrelated, but maybe informative: You can use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for what you are doing too. You might also want to look at [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) if you intend to pass end-user arguments into the CMD.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example returning the remote IP. All you need to do is import `request` and access the `remote_addr` attribute.

The `request` object is local to the current request. See [The Request Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/) for more information.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world', 'remote-ip': request.remote_addr}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```