# Python code to track ip address of machine for my website?

Tags: python, mysql

I am on python project where I want track IP address of machine and if the ip address is match with the IP address in mysql database only then allowed to proceed when I login to my hosted website. The number of IP address in database are also limited.

So if there any code please help me with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does anyone "access" your "Python project"? Are you using some web framework…? If so, it likely has some sort of `request` object from which you can get the IP.

Comment: Can you guide me how to deal with this "request" object?? I am stuck at this, not able to proceed further?

Comment: Don't ignore the first part of my comment. *We* need more information here to help *you*.

Comment: Yes, I am using flask web framework, basically its info I can't share about how any body will access my project. I just can share that the website should be able to match Machine IP address with IP address in the mysql database.

Comment: Well then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760309/476

Comment: Is it possible to get mac address for same project?

Comment: No. <minimum comment length filler>