# Getting "Unresolved reference 'app'" despite importing Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to implement the get_my_ip() method from flask. I'm getting an unresolved reference despite importing the relevant packages. I found solutions for similar issues that say that I have folder named 'app', which causes the problem, but I couldn't find such folder.

The code:

```
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/get_my_ip", methods=["GET"])
def get_my_ip():
    return jsonify({'ip': request.remote_addr}), 200
```

The function is called as follows:

```
with open('file.txt, 'a') as f:
    f.write(f'ip: {get_my_ip()}')
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't actually defined `app`. It's not a folder, it's a `Flask` object that you need to create

Comment: You mean calling the function? I added a function call now.

Comment: Oof, I'm not sure what that edit is about but it definitely isn't what I was suggesting. So you want the app route to write to a file?

Comment: Actually, I'm utterly confused now. You're trying to piggyback on Flask to grab an IP but you don't want to run an actual application? I guess it's an ingenious concept, but I can't think of any way to make that work.

Comment: I'm writing a server and I need to get users' ip.
From what I found, the only way to do that is with flask. That's the only reason I'm trying to use flask.

Comment: This looks like it is trying to debug a weird server setup, if that is true you might look into [ServerFault.SE](https://serverfault.com/tour) which focuses on IT systems within business environments (like servers)

Comment: It seems you got that code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760309/2745495. That answer does not show how a Flask `app` instance is supposed to be created first (since that wasn't the point of that Q&A). See Flask's [Minimal Application](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) tutorial to understand what `app` is and how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question **title**

You haven't actually defined `app`. You can't use the decorator to add routes to an application that you haven't even defined.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__) # See here

@app.route("/get_my_ip", methods=["GET"])
def get_my_ip():
    return jsonify({'ip': request.remote_addr}), 200
```

I strongly suggest [The Flask Megatutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) because this is a fundamental misunderstanding.

---

To answer **what you're trying to do** - this is horribly misguided. You're trying to snag on to some functionality from Flask without actually running an application. Flask is not a server. You could have any number of levels of *actual* servers before things got to the level of your code. For example, Apache or Nginx, then gunicorn. All of those could capture the IP.