# Verify hostname of the server who invoked the API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, flask, aws-elb

I have an AWS ELB connected with multiple EC2s that are running the AWS Flask server. I am not sure if AWS ELB passes the complete request to EC2 or not. I know we can do the restrictions at ELB level but I want to put restrictions on only one endpoint and verify the hostname of the server who invoked the endpoint in Flask. Is it possible?

Comment: Assuming application load balancer, you can enable [proxy protocol](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html).But this gives only IP of the client, not its DNS. The IP is also available from [x-forwarded-for](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#http-headers) header.

Comment: Is there any way to verify the SSL certificate?

Comment: Maybe this doesn't fit you use case, but you could look into using ALB / WAF to enforce restrictions at the load balancer level.

Comment: Restrictions at ELB level... it sounds to me like ELB is not the right place to implement any kind of restrictions.
Restrictions sound to me as a synonym of Permissions. I'd rather design a solution based on IAM (and maybe API Gateway).
If want to keep this simple, have you consider the option of add a parameter/body to your request with the data/info you need at the other end?
HTTP does not do what you are needing/expecting.

Comment: @TeimatiniMarínMeza Yeh. That's already there. I want to add additional security as there will be only one specific client (another server) which will access one particular endpoint and I want to restrict other clients to access it.

Comment: @SanjaySharma
What about something like this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-whitelist/ ?
If your 'another server' is an EC2 instance this would be easy. Just deploy the instance into an specific ip-range.
If not in EC2 then you could enable AWS security on the APIGateway instance. Then create a role/user, and ALLOW execute-api:Invoke for you Resource only if called with that specific role/user.
Makes sense?

Comment: @TeimatiniMarínMeza  thank you so much for your time and help. I had some idea about this and as per your explanation, this seems to be one of the alternative ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import socket
from flask import request


@app.route("/your_route", methods=["GET"])
def your_route():
    hostname, aliaslist, ipaddrlist = socket.gethostbyaddr(request.remote_addr)
```

Note that relying on the remote_addr is unreliable, however as this is unrelated to the topic I will refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654607/2973474) which makes use of [ProxyFix](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/contrib/fixers/#werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix):

For more information on `socket.gethostbyaddr()` please check out: [socket.gethostbyaddr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr)

Comment: Are you sure the hostname won't be masked by ELB?

Comment: @SanjaySharma according to this you should be able to get/set an alias, how to retrieve the alias is provided in the answer. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html#resource-record-sets-elb-dns-name-procedure

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the decorator pattern for such cases i.e. you add a new config option IP_LIST with some kind of address set divided by comma.

```
IP_LIST = "127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,..."
```

After that add a new decorator function, and decorate any endpoint with the decorator.

```
def ip_verified(fn):
    """
    A custom decorator that checks if a client IP is in the list, otherwise block access.
    """

    @wraps(fn)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        ip_list_str = current_app.config['IP_LIST']
        ip_list = ip_list_str.split(",") if ip_list_str else []

        if request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For"):
            remote_ip = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")[0]
        else:
            remote_ip = request.remote_addr

        if remote_ip not in ip_list:
            return "Not sufficient privileges", 403

        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_view

@app.route("/your_route", methods=["GET"])
@ip_verified
def your_route():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [Network Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) which preserves the IP address of the client making the request. You can even have the NLB do [the TLS termination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-tls-listener.html) just like an ELB. An NLB does not alter the data in the network request, with the exception of TLS termination if you choose to use that.